Users can change their display name and avatar on meta sites separately from the main site
For the last month, my account on Meta Super User has used the display name "Meta Jeremy", even though my account on Super User itself just uses the name "Jeremy". (There are various events that trigger a sync, so the name may have been overwritten by the time you read this post, but this is true at time of posting, and for the last month.)
This is possible because there's a /users/signup/thanks route that's used as part of one of the new sign-up flows, which allows users to change their display name and avatar. It has inadvertently been enabled on meta sites as well as main sites, though profile controls are generally supposed to be removed/disabled on meta sites.

Nice, I now have a "Meta" prefix on my name ;)

I assume this means I could have a different profile image on Meta too.

The partial separation of meta and main data has always been weird. Having two separate profiles with separately stored data (including for data that's supposed to be common) is such an awkward way to do things

I feel like the Meta profile being stored separately might be a bit of a necessity with it being MSO running on a different server than SO IIRC (doesn't change it being weird though).

@dan1st The server being separate does not matter; it's a database thing, and there's nothing technical preventing a shared table between main and meta for account details (aside questionable decisions made by SE while implementing child metas) regardless of whether MSO and SO run on separate servers. There are many different ways to implement it on a database level that would work, including in a worst-case scenario where meta and main have fully separate databases. The sync process means something connects to both at the same time, so meta could do that in a scenario like that

Yeah, I don't really understand why the tables are separate either. It would make sense to have a single Users table for both sites; if they [[so]] need additional data that needs to be stored independently for the profile they can use a separate table for that data. If they also wanted to avoid breaking changed, they could create a VIEW. I would like to assume that the meta/main data is stored in the same database, but in different schemas, but SEDE implies otherwise and they are separate databases, and hence why the data is duplicated.

My name reverted back to the SO version of it. It seems that the 2 tables are getting sync'd once in a while (why do you need 2 tables in the first place?!). @AbdulAzizBarkat Have you removed the "Meta" prefix yourself or it just happened?

@M-- it just happened automatically, been a few days since it happened though.
